# Error while reading NetCDF format data

Tags: r, netcdf, netcdf4

I am having aquaMODIS chlorophyll data in NetCDF format for the whole world.

I want to crop only the area of `longitude 70-85` and `latitude 4-18`, from the whole data. Then I want to aggregate the data and I also want to plot the data after aggregation.

However, I have faced a problem while reading the data:

> Error in в ncvar_get(mayWEEK1) :first argument (nc) is not of class ncdf4!

Kindly guide me on this matter.

An example of nc-data is available [here](https://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi/getfile/A20081772008184.L3m_8D_SST_sst_4km.nc). My syntax is as follows:

```
# Adding packages             
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)
# Loading the data
mayWEEK1 <- "E:/NIOdisseratation_WORK/Aqua_MODIS_chlorophyll/MAY/2003/2003MAY_week1.nc"
ncfWEEK1 <- brick(mayWEEK1, var="chlor_a")

# Aggregation
mayfinal <- raster::aggregate(ncfWEEK1, 2)

# Cropping
rc1 <- crop(mayfinal, extent(70, 85, 4, 18))
plot(rc1)
```

Comment: Anyone is there....

Comment: It would help if you describe exactly what doesn't work (*"but facing problem."* is not very informative), and preferably, help others reproduce the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The problem is that your variables `mayWEEK1` and `mayWEEK2` are characters; you don't read data from .nc file. You should use something like `ncvar_get()` from `ncdf4.

Comment: Like I told you TWICE in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48317168/unable-to-get-the-dimensions-of-netcdf-data-want-to-extract-values-of-variables) you really need to provide a minimal reproducible example and describe the problem you have in more detail. 'facing problem' does not tell us what's wrong. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I would recommend reading [what have you tried](https://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) to learn guidelines for using online forums to solve your problem

Comment: https://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi/getfile/A20081772008184.L3m_8D_SST_sst_4km.nc This is the link to the data. Kindly go to this link.

Comment: Ekatef,, Thankx but it shows error,,Error in ncvar_get("E:/NIOdisseratation_WORK/Aqua_MODIS_chlorophyll/MAY/2003/2003MAY_week1.nc") : 
  first argument (nc) is not of class ncdf4!

Comment: You should use as an argument of `ncvar_get()` an object of ncdf4 class (e.g., `file_nc_obj` in my answer bellow) instead of a string "E:/NIOdisseratation...". Besides, `ncvar_get()` requires a number of arguments which you should define basing on your understanding of data structure in your nc-file.

Comment: Since the question is closed I cannot answer it, and I have edited the question instead to show you how to approach it.

Answer (score 3):

**UPD** according to suggestions @RobertH

Two approaches to read your data from a netCDF file were proposed as a result of our discussion.

## With 'raster' package

If you are focused on fast visualization of your data, then the most natural way is to use `brick()` function of `raster` package:

```
var_name <- "sst" # for the example file  or "chlor_a" for your chkorophyll data    
ncfWEEK1 <- brick(mayWEEK1, varname = var_name)
```

The resulted `ncfWEEK1` is of `RasterBrick` class. Then you may use `print()` method of this class to look on the structure and attributes of your data contained in `ncfWEEK1 as simple

```
raster::print(test_brick_box)
```

Note, that further manipulation with data stored as a `RasterBrick` class may be quite tricky, however.

## With 'ncdf4' package

If you prefer to read your data into the simplest R structures (arrays of doubles), then `ncdf4` may be a better solution. However, reading of your data will look a little more complicated:

**First of all**, you have to open the file

```
file_nc_obj <- nc_open(file_to_open_name, verbose = TRUE)
```

Actually, it's better to set `verbose = FALSE` if you have still found a proper way to handle your data. But your may find helpful to begin with `verbose = TRUE` to check how your file is being loaded.

**The second step** is to have a look on structure of the data in the file. The variable `file_nc_obj` is an R object of ncdf4 class. Actually, is has a list-like structure

```
str(file_nc_obj, max = 1)
```

That means that you may assess each in-built property of `file_nc_obj` like a list component, e.g.

```
nc_dim_list <- file_nc_obj$dim
```

Besides, there are some in-built attributes in the nc-file itself; they may be important as well:

```
# read nc-attributes
fileForProc_attributes <- ncatt_get(file_nc_obj,varid=0)
str(fileForProc_attributes)
```

**The third step** is actually reading of your nc data with `ncvar_get()`. There are two general recommendations: 1) please check carefully help to `ncvar_get()` of the `ncdf4` package; 2) use your findings from the **step two** to define request in a proper way.

The variables from nc-file attached as an example (which contains spatial data for the sea surface tempurature `"sst"`) may be read as follows:

```
var_lon <- ncvar_get(file_nc_obj,"lon")
var_lat <- ncvar_get(file_nc_obj,"lat")
var_value <- ncvar_get(file_nc_obj,"sst")
test_units <- ncatt_get(file_nc_obj, "sst" ,"units")$value
start_time <- ncatt_get(file_nc_obj, 0, "time_coverage_start")$value
end_time <- ncatt_get(file_nc_obj, 0, "time_coverage_end")$value
```

**The fourth step** is do not forget to close your file

```
nc_close(file_nc_obj)
```

After that you will have the data ready for analysis and visualization.

Comment: You are wrong to say that  "First of all, you have to open the file". In this context, of spatial aggregation and cropping with the raster package, the solution is `brick(filename)`. File opening and closing, ncvar_get, etc happens behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions. I will try to implement them and get my result as expected. And will let you know about the result.

Comment: @ RobertH Many thanks for your comment! I had an impression that OP was intended to use `ncdf4` for data reading. And it seems to me that such an approach has some serious advantages. However, I completely agree that `brick()` gives a very elegant solution and have updated the answer to include your suggestions.