# Extracting data from NetCDF file in r

Tags: r, netcdf, netcdf4

I am trying to load data from a NetCDF file to r and continue having issues even after following a couple tutorials and SO posts. This is the first time I work with NetCDF so I am unsure what I am doing wrong. I have tried both with the ncdf4 and raster packages.
I still don't fully understand the code or how these files get converted/used so apologize for the long code example, but I don't know what I am doing wrong.

The data (NetCDF) I am trying to load has Sea Surface Temperatures and I accessed [here](https://psl.noaa.gov/data/gridded/data.kaplan_sst.html).
I tried following [this](https://pjbartlein.github.io/REarthSysSci/netCDF.html) tutorial and did the following:

```
# load the ncdf4 package
library(ncdf4)
dname <- "sst"
ncin <- nc_open("raw/SST/sst.mon.anom.nc")
print(ncin)
# get longitude and latitude
lon <- ncvar_get(ncin,"lon")
nlon <- dim(lon)
head(lon)
#[1]  2.5  7.5 12.5 17.5 22.5 27.5
lat <- ncvar_get(ncin,"lat")
nlat <- dim(lat)
head(lat)
#[1] -87.5 -82.5 -77.5 -72.5 -67.5 -62.5

print(c(nlon,nlat))
#[1] 72 36

# get time
time <- ncvar_get(ncin,"time")
head(time)
#[1] 20453 20484 20513 20544 20574 20605

tunits <- ncatt_get(ncin,"time","units")
nt <- dim(time)
nt
#[1] 2005

tunits
#$hasatt
#[1] TRUE

#$value
#[1] "days since 1800-1-1 00:00:00"

# get temperature
tmp_array <- ncvar_get(ncin,dname)
dlname <- ncatt_get(ncin,dname,"long_name")
dunits <- ncatt_get(ncin,dname,"units")
fillvalue <- ncatt_get(ncin,dname,"_FillValue")
dim(tmp_array)
#[1]   72   36 2005

# get global attributes
title <- ncatt_get(ncin,0,"title")
institution <- ncatt_get(ncin,0,"institution")
datasource <- ncatt_get(ncin,0,"source")
references <- ncatt_get(ncin,0,"references")
history <- ncatt_get(ncin,0,"history")
Conventions <- ncatt_get(ncin,0,"Conventions")

nc_close("raw/SST/sst.mon.anom.nc") #Error in nc$safemode : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
ls()

library(chron)

# convert time -- split the time units string into fields
tustr <- strsplit(tunits$value, " ")
tdstr <- strsplit(unlist(tustr)[3], "-")
tmonth <- as.integer(unlist(tdstr)[2])
tday <- as.integer(unlist(tdstr)[3])
tyear <- as.integer(unlist(tdstr)[1])
chron(time,origin=c(tmonth, tday, tyear))

# replace netCDF fill values with NA's
tmp_array[tmp_array==fillvalue$value] <- NA

length(na.omit(as.vector(tmp_array[,,1])))
#[1] 1203

# get a single slice or layer (January) #Im assuming this is where things 
#start going wrong but not sure what to change/do differently 
m <- 1
tmp_slice <- tmp_array[,,m]
dim(tmp_slice)
#[1] 72 36

lonlat <- as.matrix(expand.grid(lon,lat))
dim(lonlat)
#[1] 2592    2

tmp_vec <- as.vector(tmp_slice)
length(tmp_vec)
#[1] 2592

# create dataframe and add names
tmp_df01 <- data.frame(cbind(lonlat,tmp_vec))
names(tmp_df01) <- c("lon","lat",paste(dname,as.character(m), sep="_"))
head(na.omit(tmp_df01), 10)

write.table(na.omit(tmp_df01),"cru_tmp_1a.csv", row.names=FALSE, sep=",")
```

This creates a csv with lon, lat, and sst_1 columns but the longitude values seem wrong and it is not providing me any dates which I assume should be included in this.

I tried to continue following the tutorial linked above and part 3.4.1 (reshape whole array) is not looking right.

```
# reshape the array into vector
tmp_vec_long <- as.vector(tmp_array)
length(tmp_vec_long)

# reshape the vector into a matrix
tmp_mat <- matrix(tmp_vec_long, nrow=nlon*nlat, ncol=nt)
dim(tmp_mat)

head(na.omit(tmp_mat))
```

this seems to result in a blank array..?

Because this is not working for me and I am feeling stuck, I also tried following [this](https://help.marine.copernicus.eu/en/articles/6328012-how-to-convert-netcdf-to-csv-using-r) other tutorial also using the ncdf4 package but slightly different approach. I get an error once I get to Step 4 while trying to create "the coordinate matrix".
I then tried [this](https://help.marine.copernicus.eu/en/articles/5040824-how-to-open-and-visualize-copernicus-marine-data-in-r) other tutorial - but no luck.
I also tried what was suggested in [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48395379/error-while-reading-netcdf-format-data).

Additionally, I tried the same methods using a different NetCDF data just in case ([AMO](https://stateoftheocean.osmc.noaa.gov/atm/amo.php)

I will most likely be working with more NetCDF so just trying to find the best workflow to convert these into csv files and use them in r.

## To clarify, why is this not working? How can I access data in this format (netcdf)?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please ask a clear question? What are you actually asking. You just seem to have provided us with a narrative without a clear question

Comment: Im asking how to access NetCDF data. Why did what I try not work correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `terra` package for this job like

```
library(terra)

#Read the nc file
sst <- rast("sst.mean.anom.nc")
time(sst)

#Convert it into data frame
df <- as.data.frame(sst, xy = T) 
df1 <- subset(df, select = -c(x, y))
names(df1) <- time(sst) 

#Write the data in csv file
write.csv(cbind.data.frame(subset(df, select = c(x, y)), df1), "Try.csv")
```

Comment: thank you this seems to have worked for the sst.mean.anom.nc (NC_FORMAT_NETCDF4_CLASSIC). This did not work for another netcdf file (AMO) that is NC_FORMAT_CLASSIC. Does the terra approach not work with older formats? Thanks!